# Generate sub numbers from number (remove last number each time)

Tags: python, algorithm, split, integer

```
def sub(number):
tmp = []
tmp.append(number)
while len(str(number)) > 1:
    tmp.append(int(str(number)[:-1]))
    number = int(str(number)[:-1])
return tmp
```

In this function I try to make this output, something like this:

```
Input: 1234
output: [1234, 123, 12, 1]
```

Now my question is there any more efficient way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide by `10, 10**2, 10**3` and so on and keep the integer part.

See [`Floor Division (//)`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html)

1-Liner using list comprehension

```
[1234//10**i for i in range(len(str(1234)))]
```

Or

```
ans = [] 
for i in range(len(str(1234))):
    ans.append(1234//10**i )
```

Output:

```
[1234, 123, 12, 1]
```

Comment: Or completely remove string operations and just divide the last value by 10: `while (number): ans.append(number)  number //=10 `